# Read files by device/inode order?

Tags: performance, readfile

I'm interested in an efficient way to read a large number of files on the disk. I want to know if I sort files by device and then by inode I'll got some speed improvement against natural file reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, optimisation techniques for file access are too tied to the architecture of your storage subsystem for them to be something as simple as a sorting algorithm.

1) You can effectively multiply the read data rate if your files are spread into multiple physical drives (not just partitions) and you read two or more files in parallel from different drives. This one is probably the only method that is easy to implement.

2) Sorting the files by name or inode number does not really change anything in the general case. What you'd want is to sort the files by the *physical location of their blocks* on the disk, so that they can be read with minimal seeking. There are quite a few obstacles however:

- Most filesystems do not provide such information to userspace applications, unless it's for debugging reasons.
- The blocks themselves of each file can be spread all over the disk, especially on a mostly full filesystem. There is no way to read multiple files sequentially without seeking back and forth.
- You are assuming that your process is the only one accessing the storage subsystem. Once there is at least someone else doing the same, every optimisation you come up with goes out of the window.
- You are trying to be smarter than the operating system and its own caching and I/O scheduling mechanisms. It's very likely that by trying to second-guess the kernel, i.e. the only one that really *knows* your system and your usage patterns, you will make things worse.
- Don't you think e.g. PostreSQL pr Oracle would have used a similar technique if they could? When the DB is installed on a proper filesystem they let the kernel do its thing and don't try to second-guess its decisions. Only when the DB is on a raw device do the specialised optimisation algorithms that take physical blocks into account come into play.
- You should also take the specific properties of your storage devices into account. Modern SSDs, for example, make traditional seek-time optimisations obsolete.

Comment: Regarding parallel file access - it can also speed up single-disk scenarios significantly by giving the kernel a bigger work-queue to do disk-scheduling on.

However, it may come at a cost. Other applications, especially ones sending fully sequential I/O, may get their I/O queries literally slowed down in the queue.

Comment: (2) is wrong, it has been shown that userspace sorting of files by inode and physical location does improve performance by large integer factors (of course dependent on file size, more so for small files). See [this paper](http://home.ifi.uio.no/paalh/publications/files/ipccc09.pdf) and [presentation](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/linux_disk_io_performance_havard_espeland.pdf), which include useful graphs. They report that their `qtar` tar implementation using `FIEMAP` is 4x faster in tarring the Linux kernel source tree.

Comment: I've also made my own quick implementation of sorting files by device order: [diskorder](https://github.com/nh2/diskorder)

Answer (score 7):

There are vast speed improvements to be had from reading files in physical order from rotating storage.  Operating system I/O scheduling mechanisms only do any real work if there are several processes or threads contending for I/O, because they have no information about what files you plan to read in the future.  Hence, other than simple read-ahead, they usually don't help you at all.

Furthermore, Linux worsens your access patterns during directory scans by returning directory entries to user space in hash table order rather than physical order.  Luckily, Linux also provides system calls to determine the physical location of a file, and whether or not a file is stored on a rotational device, so you can recover some of the losses.  See for example this patch I submitted to dpkg a few years ago:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-dpkg/2009/11/msg00002.html

This patch does not incorporate a test for rotational devices, because this feature was not added to Linux until 2012:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ef00f59c95fe6e002e7c6e3663cdea65e253f4cc

I also used to run a patched version of mutt that would scan Maildirs in physical order, usually giving a 5x-10x speed improvement.

Note that inodes are small, heavily prefetched and cached, so opening files to get their physical location before reading is well worth the cost.  It's true that common tools like tar, rsync, cp and PostgreSQL do not use these techniques, and the simple truth is that this makes them unnecessarily slow.

Comment: You are right. See also this question, in the comment of which I link to a paper that has implemented disk-order reading for `tar`, getting large speedups: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124527/speed-up-copying-1000000-small-files#comment579824_124583

Comment: I've emailed the authors, asking whether they could release `qtar` as open source; it is now at https://github.com/chlunde/qtar

Answer (score 2):

Back in the 1970s I proposed to our computer center that reading/writing from/to disk would be faster overall if they organized the queue of disk reads and/or writes in such a way as to minimize the seek time and I was told by the computer center that their experiments and information from IBM that many studies had been made of several techniques and that the overall throughput of JOBS (not just a single job) was most optimal if disk reads/writes were done in first come first serve order. This was an IBM batch system.